# Codeigniter passing checkbox array values to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Just want to pass checkbox array values to mysql database table after submitting the form (table columns: id, fanta, cola, sprite) . Each value should be inserted in seperate field (i.e. without using implode/explode functions). The best solution will be just passing "1" (if selected ) or "0" (if not selected). Please help me :)

**Here is My Model:**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Model_example2 extends CI_Model {
  function __construct()
 {
  //Call the Model constructor
   parent::__construct();
 }
public function did_add() {
        $data = array(              
        'fanta' => $this->input->post('fanta'),
        'cola' => $this->input->post('cola'),
        'sprite' => $this->input->post('sprite'),         
                     );
        $query = $this->db->insert('table_example2', $data);
        if ($query) {
            return true;} 
        else {
        return false;}
    }
}
```

**Here is My View:**

```
             <div >
             <?php              
             $this->load->helper("form","file","html","url");
             echo $message;
             echo validation_errors();
             echo form_open("example2/add");
             echo form_label("Drink:<br>","type");
             ?>                   
<input type="checkbox" name="types[]" value="fanta" <?php echo set_checkbox('types[]', 'fanta', FALSE); ?>/>Fanta<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="types[]" value="cola" <?php echo set_checkbox('types[]', 'cola', FALSE); ?>/>Coca Cola<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="types[]" value="sprite" <?php echo set_checkbox('types[]', 'sprite', FALSE); ?>/>Sprite<br />
             echo form_submit("Submit", "Add");
             echo form_close();
             </div>
```

**Here is My Controller:**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Example2 extends MX_Controller {
    public function add() {                 
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->load->model('model_example2');          
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('types[]', 'Drink','required');           
            if($this->form_validation->run()){
            $this->model_example2->did_add(); 
            $data["message"] = "Great job!";
            $this->load->view("view_add_success",$data);
            }
            else {
            $data["message"] = "";  
            $this->load->view("view_example2",$data);
            }           
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the column name to store type in db? do you have column name like "fanta" , "cola" etc..? if so, then you can name checkbox with fanta, cola etc..

Comment: there are three column names: fanta, cola, sprite. I named checkbox "types" in order to validate checkbox fields (at least one should be selected (>=1)): $this->form_validation->set_rules('types[]', 'Drink','required');

Comment: then you can name your checkbox with field names

Comment: but then I won't be able to validate checkbox group so that at least one should be selected ( >=1 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this

```
public function did_add() {

    $types = $this->input->post('types');
    $data = array(
        'fanta' => 0,
        'cola' => 0,
        'sprite' => 0,
    );
    foreach ($types as $type) {
        $data[$type] = 1;
    }

    $query = $this->db->insert('table_example2', $data);
    if ($query) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your code is the perfect solution of the above-mentioned problem. I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Hi Minhaz, perhaps you could have a look on my question and help me to find the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512209/codeigniter-select-from-where