# Codeigniter select- from- where

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Just want to make codeigniter filter form work. For example, if "Samsung" will be selected from dropdown list and "2G" from checkbox fields, rows with id 1 and 4 should be returned. But my model returns nothing.I think the problem is in IF statement of the model but I cannot find out what is the exact reason. Please help me.

Here is my database table:

[image: database table]

Here is my filter form:

[image: filter form]

Here is My Model:

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

        class Model_example extends CI_Model {

          function __construct()
         { 
           parent::__construct();
         }

        public function did_filter() {


       $types = $this->input->post('types');

            $data = array(
                '2g' => 0,
                    '3g' => 0,
                    '4g' => 0,                
                         );                  
            foreach ($types as $type) {
                                           $data[$type] == 1;
                                      }
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('table_example');
    $this->db->where('phone', $this->input->post('phone'));

                if (
 $query = $this->db->get()   
    )     
    {
    if (
        (('2g' == 1) AND ($data['2g'] == 1)) OR
        (('3g' == 1) AND ($data['3g'] == 1)) OR  
        (('4g' == 1) AND ($data['4g'] == 1)))
       {                 
       return $result = $query->result_array();
       } 
        else {
        return false;
        }               
           }

    else {
    return false;
    } 

            }  
        }
```

Here is My View number 1:

```
 <?php 

             $this->load->helper("form","file");

             echo validation_errors();              

             echo form_open_multipart("example/search");

             echo form_label("Phone:<br>","phone");
             $data = array(
                  "" => "Select Phone",
                  "samsung" => "Samsung",
                  "htc" => "HTC",
                  "nokia" => "Nokia",
                );
             echo form_dropdown('phone', $data, set_value('phone'));

             echo br(5);
              ?> 

             <?php echo form_label("Network Type:<br>","type");?>                   
<input type="checkbox" name="types[]" value="2g" id="types"  <?php echo set_checkbox('types[]', '2g', FALSE); ?>/>2G<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="types[]" value="3g" id="types" <?php echo set_checkbox('types[]', '3g', FALSE); ?>/>3G<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="types[]" value="4g" id="types" <?php echo set_checkbox('types[]', '4g', FALSE); ?>/>4G<br />
<br />          
             <?php

             echo br(1);

             echo form_submit("filterSearch", "Search");

             echo form_close();

             ?>
```

Here is My View number 2:

```
<?php 

       print_r($result);
```

Here is my controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Example extends MX_Controller {

    public function index() { //main function

        $this->load->view("view_example");
    }

public function search() { 

            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->load->model('model_example');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Phone','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('types[]', 'Network Type','required'); 

           if($this->form_validation->run()) {

            $data["result"] = $this->model_example->did_filter();


            $this->load->view("view_search_results",$data); 

            }
            else
            {

            $this->load->view("view_no_search_results");

             }

    }
}
```

Comment: @TProDeveloper don't let Ryan discourage you -- the more details the better when asking questions here.

Comment: It won't return anything cause you placed return $result in an empty IF statement. Add those conditions in the where clause.

Comment: I already tried. It did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it should work, i gave you two option for where so use the one that you need

```
 public function did_filter() {

    $types = $this->input->post('types');

    //list of types column name you can ignore this part by in cases someone change the value in html your query will fail so i am keeping this
    $data = array(
        '2g' => 0,
        '3g' => 0,
        '4g' => 0,
    );

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('table_example');
    $this->db->where('phone', $this->input->post('phone'));

    // if you want to use and where use this block, or use the next block the is commented out
    foreach ($types as $type) {
        if (isset($data[$type])) { // this making sure that your column is correct 
            $this->db->where($type, 1);
        }
    }

    /**
    //If you want your checkbox to work as or, ie if 2g and 3g select and you want to show any check box match. 
    //In case of your example still it will give row 1 and 4, but if you use fist block it will give you row 1 only because row 1 got both 2g and 3g
    $or_where = array();
    foreach ($types as $type) {
        if (isset($data[$type])) { // this makeing sure that your colum is correct 
            $or_where[] = "$type = 1";
        }
    }
    if (count($or_where) > 0) {
        $where = implode(' OR ', $or_where); // make the or where for array
        $this->db->where("($where)");
    }
     * 
     */

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query && $query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result_array();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Minhaz, thanks for your reply. I really appreciate your help. I want my checkbox to work as or, so I used the second block of your code but, unfortunately, there are several syntax errors for implode() function which I could not fix because it was a little bit complicated for me, could you please check it?

Comment: I modify the code, try this one, i made it fully simple it should work and you will able to understand to. Mainly the implode should give the query like  `$this->db->where("(2g=1 OR 3g=1)")`

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to do for several weeks :) You are the best :) Thank you very much Minhaz! I really appreciate your great support!

Comment: Hi Minhaz, Hope you are doing well :) Could you please have a look at my problem. Perhaps you can see my mistake. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23976730/codeigniter-pass-variable-to-php-file-using-ajax-jquery-json

Answer (score 0):

try this model

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Model_example extends CI_Model
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function did_filter()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('table_example',array('phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),'types' => $this->input->post('types')));

        return $query->result_array();   
    }
}
```